# Using of Spring Security in Cloud & autoscaling of web application

Tags: spring, amazon-ec2, cloud, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Some Web Application is managed by Spring 4.0 Framework, the [Spring Security 3.2](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/16/spring-security-3-2-0-release-released) is used also to authenticate users with remember Me feature.
The remember Me and Security is realized by JDBC Support (the needed data are saved in database).
 A lot of Spring Beans is used, that are created as "spring" [singletons](http://www.e-zest.net/blog/spring-singleton-and-java-singleton-pattern/)

This Web Applicaton runs in TOMCAT7 Servlet Container, that installed in "classic" Host Sever.

This web application will be runs  in production within TOMCAT7, that managed by some Cloud Provider - either in [AWS Elastic Beanstalk](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) or in [EC2 Instance](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) direct with instaled TOMCAT with **autoscaling**

That means, that at the first moment runs only **ONE** EC2 Instance, that has running TOMCAT Server 1. This server has initialized Spring Beans, holding in JVM 1.

But at "peak time" the second instance of EC2 will be started. The TOMCAT2 Server will be started also.

Is it possible, that a USER1, that was authenticated at first moment on TOMCAT1, have a problem with authentication and other business operations realized in WEb Application, if the load balancer routes the user1'Requests after start of TOMMCAT2 to TOMCAT2???

i don't know, whether Spring 4.0 or Spring Security are stateless by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Elastic Load Balancer sticky sessions for your application.

Read about using Sticky Sesions here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_StickySessions.html

Read about using Sticky Sessions with Elastic Beanstalk here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.elb.html

Read about Stickiness policy here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html

Comment: If sticky sessions will be used, so some of clients to lose their sessions and require logins again. if load balancer routes the client to application server, that is failed.